# How can I swap two variable's value considering with the memory management and is there any better way to solve this?

Tags: c

I want to swap two variable's value. This is what I have tried:

method 1:

```c
int a = 5, b = 6;
int temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

method 2:

```c
int a = 5, b = 6;
int *p = a;

a = b;
b = p;
```

method 3:

```c
int a = 5, b = 6;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Is there any effective method to solve this swapping problem and consider the memory management?

Comment: Please don't tag multiple unrelated languages, only the one you're actually programming in. Please [edit] your question to remove one of the language tags.

Comment: And assuming C, because the second example, that second example is wrong and makes no sense.

Comment: And you mention "memory management", but why? What is the actual and underlying problem you have? Why is "memory management" so important? Why does it need to be "effective"?

Comment: What does "consistent with memory management" mean? Everybody just does (1).

Comment: Swapping tro integer variables is trivial, "memory management" and certainly "dynamic-memory-management" are irrelevant unless you want to deliberately over complicate a simple problem and use _more_ memory.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: See also [Universal array element swap in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50559106/15168) and [error: cannot convert '`double*`' to '`char*`' for argument '1' to '`void swap(char*, char*, unsigned int)`'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49871989/15168).

Answer (score 1):

Your methods:

1. method 1 - OK
2. method 2 - not OK
   Your second method is completely wrong and invoked undefined behaviour. You assign **the pointer** with `int` value converted to pointer to `int`. Then you do the opposite conversion.

```
    int a = 5, b = 6;
    int *p = a;  //!!!wrong and compiler will warn you!!!!
    
    a = b;
    b = p;
```

3. method 3 - dangerous as you may **overflow** the `int` values. You can do this if your intermediate values have a larger size.

```
    int a = 5, b = 6;
    long long int aa = a; bb = b;

    aa = aa + bb;
    b = aa - bb;
    a = aa - bb;
```

> Is there any effective method to solve this swapping problem and
> consider the memory management?

- do not even think about it as optimizing compilers will not use any memory at all. Do not overthink optimizations.

Example:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

This function does not use any extra memory even if compiled with `-Og` optimization (a very low level used for debugging)

```
swap:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
        ret
```

Also, remember that it can be inlined so there will not be a call to the function.

Comment: @OP If the original intent was to somehow save memory, you can see how using the third way correctly uses two extra variables. That wouldn't be the case if you'd simply use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is the correct option.

(2) doesn't compile, and I have no idea what was your intent there.

(3) is pointless. Firstly, it can overflow and cause undefined behavior. There's a similar technique called [XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm), that's not prone to overflows: `a ^= b ^= a ^= b;`, but it's mostly a clever trick with no practical use. Wikipedia [suggests to avoid it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice) for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and pointing out the second method is no sense of solving the issue and got the point 

for the method 3 can you explain a bit more how it's exactly working with the example.

Comment: @MohamedMRI Just google "xor swap".

Answer (score 0):

About the third method, consider the case where `a + b` would expand to a value greater than `INT_MAX`. That'd cause signed integer overflow which would invoke undefined behavior.

```
a = INT_MAX - 1000;
b = INT_MAX;

a = a + b;  // Undefined behavior.
```

Were `a` and `b` of type `unsigned`, the value would have wrapped around and this would have worked correctly.

Answer (score -1):

for swap you can use a `swap` function and pass by reference .i.e. in the caller function the values are changed in the pointer, instead of multiple copying.

```c
void swap(int *a, int *b){
  int temp = *a; //temp is on stack memory. i.e. local variable
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

int main(){
  int a = 5, b = 7;
  swap(&a, &b);
  return 0;
}
```

In the `main` the two pointers are also on the `stack` memory, but you can pass any type of pointer in the swap, i.e. pass-by-reference.